# Unity using “−” (U+2212) as negative sign in generated C++

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to build my project (I have tried building for Android and Universal Windows Platform), building fails due to a `MINUS SIGN (U+2212)` character being used in the generated C++ as a negative sign.  I am in Unity 2020.2/Android 11 SDK/GPGS 10; I built successfully with Unity 2019/Android 10 SDK/GPGS 9.

I have searched for “−” (and “2212” for good measure) in all `asset`, `cs`, `meta`, `prefab`, `txt`, `unity`, and `xml` files in the project and found nothing (other than a coincidental file ID `616832212`, sprite ID `9561e3c67a82d7f448852212eb8fac6b`, and binary files that technically match).  I also tried having Unity reinstall packages and rebuild `Library`; no luck.

For a UWP build, I opened `[build output directory]\Il2CppOutputProject\Source\il2cppOutput\Generic8.cpp` and confirmed the “−” character appears in that way repeatedly in the file—e.g.,

```cpp
19990:IL_0063:
19991:  {
19992:      return (int32_t)(−1);
19993:  }
19994:}
```

The error for an Android build is:

```
Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\[path to project folder]\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Android\armeabi-v7a\il2cppOutput\Assembly-CSharp.cpp:20814:155: warning: treating Unicode character <U+2212> as identifier character rather than as '-' symbol [-Wunicode-homoglyph]
                AndroidClient_InvokeCallbackOnGameThread_TisUIStatus_t34F64DC1927A392210216047169D4E196183BD14_m78B26B077A1A979B11C5596B45DC6E9A1A2929B6(L_1, ((int32_t)<U+2212>3), /*hidden argument*/AndroidClient_InvokeCallbackOnGameThread_TisUIStatus_t34F64DC1927A392210216047169D4E196183BD14_m78B26B077A1A979B11C5596B45DC6E9A1A2929B6_RuntimeMethod_var);
                                                                                                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~
C:\[path to project folder]\Library\Il2cppBuildCache\Android\armeabi-v7a\il2cppOutput\Assembly-CSharp.cpp:20814:155: error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers
                AndroidClient_InvokeCallbackOnGameThread_TisUIStatus_t34F64DC1927A392210216047169D4E196183BD14_m78B26B077A1A979B11C5596B45DC6E9A1A2929B6(L_1, ((int32_t)<U+2212>3), /*hidden argument*/AndroidClient_InvokeCallbackOnGameThread_TisUIStatus_t34F64DC1927A392210216047169D4E196183BD14_m78B26B077A1A979B11C5596B45DC6E9A1A2929B6_RuntimeMethod_var);
                                                                                                                                                                        ^~~~~~~~
```

(And then the same thing continues to repeat for dozens more instances.)

Comment: That's really interesting and bizarre. What's the full version number of unity that you're using?

Comment: Sounds like you should report it as a bug to unity.

Comment: @Ruzihm It was 2020.2.0f1.  I ended up just reverting to the last LTS release (2019.4.17f1), where this does not occur.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue, switching to UK (from Sweden) solved it
(not physically, changed in System settings: Language/Region)

Comment: I've had the same issue with Swedish as system language on macOS and c++ files generated by Android build using Visual Studio for macOS and building a cross-platform MAUI mobile application (though command-line building with `dotnet` worked without problem). Switching system language to English-UK solved the issue.